# Turn on Testflight beta testing in iTunes Connect stopped working

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

In iTunes Connect there is a button "TestFlight Beta Testing" in order to do just that.

I have a binary uploaded and ready. A few users are selected for testing.

This time, that button just does nothing. After tapping it, it goes green. But no invitation emails are ever sent out. If I reload the page, that button is unchecked/white. Bug or did I miss something?

**Update: it seems to be working again. Nothing to see. Move on.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also having problems sending out invites.

Seems to be an issue on Apple's end - TestFlight is experiencing problems: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Answer (score -1):

During last days it doesn't work for me. Like an author I push the button but any mails don't send.

Comment: it works! I unchek button "TestFlight Beta Testing" , and check it again.